# Unable to get the values from a HTML FORM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a budget tracker app using JavaScript. Took all the required steps but unable to get the values recorded into the empty array created after clicking the submit button. Below is my code.

```js
let id = document.getElementById("id").value;
let empId = document.getElementById("empID").value;
let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
let empName = document.getElementById("empname").value;
let using = document.getElementById("using").value;
let mode = document.getElementsByClassName("mode").value;
let day = document.getElementById("day").value;
let date = document.getElementById("date").value;

var expenseList = [];
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(Object.assign(expenseList, { id: empId }));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Expense Tracker Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="employee-info">
    <form class="expenesesForm">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td id="id">Employee ID:</td>
          <td>
            <input id="empID" type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="name">Name:</td>
          <td>
            <input id="empname" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="using">Paid Using:</td>
          <td>
            <select id="payment-mode">
              <option class="" value="" selected disabled>
                Select from the list
              </option>
              <option class="mode" value="card">Card</option>
              <option class="mode" value="cheque">Cheque</option>
              <option class="mode" value="cash">Cash</option>
              <option class="mode" value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="day">Date of Transaction:</td>
          <td><input id="date" type="date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <br />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

There is no error shown in the console. It is just giving an empty array after submitting the form. I'm unable to get where I'm missing something. Requesting your help.

Output I'm getting:
[id: '']

Expected output:
After filling in all the details like
Employee Id: 111
Name: abc
Paid Using: Card
Date of Transaction: 01/01/2022

The expected output after filling in the details is: [{id: 111, name: 'abc', using:'Card', Date of Transaction: '01/01/2022'}]

Requesting your help in solving this.

Thanks & Regards,
Kp

Comment: Why `Object.assign()` when `expenseList` is an _array_? And why `Object.assign(expensesList, ...)` twice?

Comment: _"Error Output I'm getting"_ - `[id: '']` is not an error

Comment: `document.getElementById("id").value` - The element with the id `id` is not an input element.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, I made the required changes as mentioned. I can't get the last comment 'The element with the id ```id``` is not an input element.'. Yes, it is not. I thought to keep it as a static value.

Comment: Only `input` elements (and `select`, `textarea`, etc.) have `value` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this code work, we have to do the following:

1. Put `method="POST" action=""` to form in HTML page
2. Put the JavaScript code in a click event, so when the user clicks submit it executes the code.
3. You are selecting elements by their id when they are `<td>` elements and retrieving their `value`, but what you have to do is select the `innerText` of the `td`.
4. I used `fromEntries` to convert the array to an object so the final code will be like below:

   ```
   document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = document.getElementById("id").innerText;
    let empId = document.getElementById("empID").value;
    let name = document.getElementById("name").innerText;
    let empName = document.getElementById("empname").value;
    let using = document.getElementById("using").innerText;
    let mode = document.getElementById("payment-mode").value;
    let day = document.getElementById("day").innerText;
    let date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    let array =[[id,empId],[name,empName],[using, mode],[day,date]];
    let expenseList = Object.fromEntries(array);
    console.log(expenseList);
   });
   ```

   and HTML code will be:

   ```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Expense Tracker Project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="employee-info">
        <form class="expenesesForm" method="POST" action="">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td id="id">Employee ID</td>
              <td>
                <input id="empID" name="empID"  type="text" placeholder="Employee ID" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="name">Name:</td>
              <td>
                <input id="empname" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="using">Paid Using</td>
              <td>
                <select id="payment-mode">
                  <option class="" value="" selected disabled>
                    Select from the list
                  </option>
                  <option class="mode" value="card">Card</option>
                  <option class="mode" value="cheque">Cheque</option>
                  <option class="mode" value="cash">Cash</option>
                  <option class="mode" value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="day">Date of Transaction</td>
              <td><input id="date" type="date" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <br />
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
   ```

Comment: yeah and i forget to tell you , when we have a select input we have to put the id of select and getElementById, not get element by class name of option

Comment: Noted. Observed in the code. Thanks again